# modify default underscore behaviour/interpretation

Tags: underscore, default

Is there any way to modify the default in-text underscore behaviour document-wide?

I'm utilising a lot of filenames, IDs and so on which often have underscores in, and LaTeX doesn't like this (`missing $ inserted....`). Its becoming laborious to change these every time. Can I do something to resolve this once and for all document-wide without breaking anything?

Comment: `\catcode\`_=12`  (and then use `\sb` to get subscripts in math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\catcode`_=12
```

and then use `\sb` to get subscripts in math

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\catcode`_=12

\begin{document}

This is a_document_with_underscores and _mathematics_ $x\sb{2}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_` as subscript prefix in math mode and the same `_` as normal character outside math mode. Try this:

```
\catcode`\_=13  \let_=\sb
\mathcode`\_="8000
\catcode`\_=12
```

Comment: This looks ideal as I do have several equations I'd prefer to not have to modify as well.